# Increment typedef enum

Tags: c, enums, typedef, state-machine

I'am writing a State-Machine for a Communication. I want to increment the state like this:

```
typedef enum{
STATE_INIT=0,
STATE_READY,
STATE_WRITE,
STATE_READ,
STATE_READ_WRITE} COM_STATES;
---
COM_STATES comStates;

void main (){
uint8_t txData = 0;
uint8_t rxData;
while(1){
if( comStates == STATE_READ_WRITE)
comStates = STATE_INIT;
comStates++;
}}
```

I know that this might seem like nonsense but I have other State-Machines as well, that need to jump from state 1 to 2 or 3 to 4 or 9 to 10 from the same function administrating the State-Machine. I don't want to write 3 if-statements

Comment: Cool, nice idea. Will be looking forward for the results. Right now the `{` `}` are misaligned and strange. Remember to indent your code properly. Here is a good guide: [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html). What is your question?

Comment: What's wrong with `comStates++`?

Comment: Sorry to say, but you are right, it is nonsense. Mixing two concepts which aren't really coming from the same domain, namely integer arithmetic and state machines, is a bad thing. You will notice when you present this to a fellow programmer (or yourself in a few months). Stay symbolic and don't share functionality regarding state change between foreign state machines - or live with an unmaintainable mess in the near future.

Comment: Then just create more enumerator objects and pass them to functions by pointer. Or I just did not understand the question correctly?

Comment: The usual thing to use with state machines in C is `switch`, but in this very simple case where there is only one path to follow, `state++;` does the job very well.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. What's the question here?